# Restoring default OEM Windows 7 account picture

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

Recently I changed my account picture from the default HP image to a skull and crossbones. When I tried to change it back, I saw that the default picture had been replaced with the skull and crossbones.

I've looked in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\Default Pictures` but the original image was not there.

Please help me I have been looking around and I really need this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a bitmap file. Check `C:\Windows\System32` for BMP files. That is where Dell stores theirs. It might be called `OemUser.bmp`, or something similar.

If that doesn't work you can search for it;

1. Go into Windows Explorer
2. Navigate to `C:\`
3. Enter `*.BMP` in the search box
4. View the results to find the image you are looking for
5. Once you find it, see what the path to the image is
6. Use the path when changing the profile picture